# Diferencias entre los archivos csproj y sln

Tags: c#

Cuando abrí el archivo **.sln** noté que no tenía nada sobre mi proyecto, en cambio, cuando ejecuté el **archivo.csproj** del mismo proyecto, noté que sí tenía acceso a todos mis controladores y entidades.

Entonces yo me pregunto, ¿cuál es la diferencia entre estas dos extensiones **.sln** y **.csproj**?

Comment: Un `.sln` o solución, puede tener más de un proyecto. También te permite cambiar el orden en que se compila cada uno.

Comment: Hola Cristian, si la respuesta te resulto util podrias marcarla como aceptada y darle un voto positivo, gracias

Answer (score 4):

**Un archivo de proyecto .csproj** contiene configuraciones sobre cómo compilar su código. Es solo un **archivo xml** que contiene la **configuración del compilador**, la **configuración del vinculador** y describe qué archivos desea compilar.

Por otra parte un **archivo .sln** **agrupa varios archivos de proyecto(.csproj)**, es decir hay un relación de tipo **1 a muchos**, donde una solución puede tener uno o más proyectos, pero un proyecto solo pertenece a una solución. También puedes verlo como una especie de jerarquía donde el **fichero .sln** es la raíz que contiene varios hijos que serían los proyectos dentro de la solución(como cuando en el explorador de Windows abres una carpeta y dentro de esta hay otras carpetas, esto es lo que se conoce como una estructura de tipo árbol o jerárquica).

**Referencia:** https://foroayuda.es/que-son-los-archivos-sln-y-vcproj-y-que-contienen/